# Angular serve fails with esm

Tags: node.js, angular, es6-modules, angular-universal

I just created a fresh Angular universal app using Angular cli. it just works fine.

however, when I just add `"type": "module"` to `package.json` and serve again (with or without rebuilding the app again) it fails with the error `Strict mode code may not include a with statement`

**reproduction steps**
1- create a new Angular universal app `ng new example && cd example && ng add @nguniversal/express-engine`
2- run `npm start` -> `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr` (suceesed)
3- add `"type": "module"` and run `npm run serve:ssr` or `npm start` again (faild with  `Strict mode code may not include a with statement`)
4- remove `"type": "module"` and run `npm run serve:ssr` without rebuilding the app (successed)

**trials**

- remove `ServerModule` from imports[] im app/app.server.module.ts
- remove `export { renderModule } from '@angular/platform-server';` in app/main.server.ts
- run `npm start` to rebuild the app (failed with the same error)

[reproduction](https://github.com/eng-dibo/tmp-angular-esm)